# Problems compiling Eclipse project with Ant

Tags: java, generics, ant

I created a reasonably big web project on Eclipse (8 months of work). I've been using Eclipse build system until now. Now I'd like to go to Ant for a number of reasons (among them, be able to add certain pre WAR tasks, like js compression and other...). I discovered that Eclipse creates a `build.xml` file automatically, with all dependencies set up. The problem is that if I try to run it, it fails and gives this error:

```
type parameters of <TypeName>TypeName cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable TypeName with upper bounds TypeName,java.lang.Object
    [javac]         return dao.getItemByProperty(propertyName, val, objectClass);
```

it besically dies beacause of an error with generics.... usually it compiles fine on Eclipse (I know it is a different compiler...). How can I have javac work with this??

The method is:

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public <TypeName> TypeName getItemByProperty(String propertyName,
            Object val, Class objectClass) {
        return dao.getItemByProperty(propertyName, val, objectClass);
    }
```

and dao.getItem... is

```
@Override
    public <TypeName> TypeName getItemByProperty(String propertyName,
            Object val, Class objectClass) {

        Session sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria criteria = sess.createCriteria(objectClass);
        criteria.add(Expression.eq(propertyName, val));
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<TypeName> results = criteria.list();

        if (results != null && results.size() != 0) {
            TypeName res = results.get(0);
            return res;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

they are in two classes that respectively implement two interface, the first for a service, the second for a dao and they are used in Spring.

Why is this happening? Is Eclipse compiler so different from javac?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Ant is actually being used, and which version of the compiler is being used? For a sanity check, try this at the command line where you are trying to run ant:

ant -v.

javac -v.

I ran into a similar situation once, where everything should work but didn't. Here Weblogic had an older version of both ant and javac than what I was trying to use, and these older version were being used instead of the ones I wanted. I ended up writing a script that explicitly set these variables in my PATH, and running the script before running the ant task.

Comment: ant is 1.8.1 and javac is 1.6.0_21

Comment: @gotch4 were these the values you were expecting?

Comment: @gotch4 If those values weren't what you were expecting, then the issue would be as I described in my post. Next step would be to see what JDK that Eclipse is using, and see if it matches the JDK that you are using. Right-click on your project in Eclipse, select 'Properties', and then go to 'Java Compiler'. The compiler (javac) that you are using in Eclipse for your project will be displayed. Also, can you post the ant target that you are running when you get the failure?